# Styleguide/Pattern Library - components with different dependencies

Tags: design-patterns, dependencies

We would like to build a pattern library (or kind of styleguide) with components that we built in past projects. Like a components resource summary page that gives you an interactive preview of each pattern, with the description and code snippets that belongs to it.

The problem is, that some projects are years old, others are just finished. So the dependencies and versions can vary. Also the way they are built can vary, let's say one is made just in Jquery, the other uses Typescript and Angular.

Is there a way (or best practise) to build a summary page of all the different components that can handle different frameworks, framework versions, node modules, plugins, JS/CSS/HTML etc. for each component independently? ...without gaining conflicts ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really sorry that in this month you have not got a single comment or answer to this question (P.S. I really like your question).

Did you already found a solution for your problem?

## Introduction

I think that you are looking for way to implement Living Pattern (Component) library in your projects. But before that let's clear out some of [confusion](https://webdevstudios.com/2016/04/07/what-is-difference-between-style-guide-and-pattern-library/) made by these terms:

1. **Style guide** - branding guidelines, baseline for style. Influence the look of a Pattern Library
2. **Pattern** / Component **library** - documented components that you can **reuse**

This is my interpretation of these terms. I think that community is still in a search for perfect definitions.

Some cites from various authors:

> A *living style guide* is a system that allows the components within the style guide to **remain in sync** with the components in the site, without having to update the code in both places! - [Nick Berens](https://css-tricks.com/style-guide-driven-development-atomic-docs/)

Existing tools

> Existing tools to help you build these component libraries often force
>   you to use a particular template language, a specific build tool or a
>   pre-determined way to organize the individual elements within your
>   library. They generate a web preview to allow you to browse your
>   rendered components, but generally aren’t able to help much when it
>   comes to integrating your component library into your build process or
>   live site. - [Fractal docs](http://fractal.build/guide)

## Solution

Half year ago there weren't such a tool that could satisfy my needs so I created my own component library generator. About [week ago](https://twitter.com/allmarkedup/status/756431320025272320), similar tool named Fractal release it's v1.0.

[Fractal](http://fractal.build/guide) - New one out there. Gives flexibility to choose templating engine. Documented, but not yet widely used.

[SourceJs](https://sourcejs.com) - Allows to code new components directly in the Style Guide. Multiple templating engine support.

[PatternLab](http://patternlab.io/) - Already long time out there. One of the most popular ones. Comes together with [Atomic Design Methodology](http://atomicdesign.bradfrost.com/chapter-2/)

[AtomicDocs](http://atomicdocs.io/) - New, beautiful, user-friendly, easy-to-install component library. But it lacks some templating engine flexibility.

## Conclusion

Challenge is to find the one that fits your needs. And at the moment I haven't found comprehensive overview and that makes choosing a bit harder. [Here](http://styleguides.io/tools.html) you can find a nice list of tools!

Feel free to ask questions.

Good Luck ;)

Comment: Hey @karlisup - Thanks a lot for that extensive answer, will check that links out! I don't get the down-vote on my question because it's an issue that isn't really solved.

Comment: YW. The topic itself is not popular in stackoverflow community. To target the right audience I would have chosen tags `pattern-library` / `component-library` / `design-system` but those are not yet available.